# Spring Boot - redirect to index.html from Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

GalleryController
package com.galleryapp.galleryapp.Controller;

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GalleryController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")

    public String homePage() {


        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Ya I am trying to redirect on my homepage from my controller . when i run my application them i will the get text "Index" on my local host 8080 ..I want The the welcome message which is in my index.html Page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid posting amendments to your question in the comments and edit the question instead. Furthermore, please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, what the issue is and what you've tried already to solve the issue. Also, please have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: Replace `RestController` with `Controller`. That's it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace `RestController` with `Controller`.

`@RestController` is a special controller used in RESTFul web services and it is the equivalent of `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`.
This is why a `String` **index** shows up in your home page instead of your page `index`.

Comment: Thanks  a lot Dfor . Its worked .Thanks for guide line .That is my first Question on stack Flow One again thanks